# Complex mysql query, specific join

Tags: mysql

I've got a problem.
I have 3 tables and I need inner join between them when selecting. Normally it would be something like

```
select `wp_fs_reports`.*,`wp_fs_agents`.`name`,`wp_rg_form`.`title`  from `wp_fs_reports`
INNER JOIN `wp_rg_form` ON (`wp_fs_reports`.`form_id` = `wp_rg_form`.`id`) 
INNER JOIN `wp_fs_agents` ON(`wp_fs_reports`.`agent_id` = `wp_fs_agents`.`id`)
```

Problem is, `wp_fs_reports.agent_id` and `wp_fs_reports.form_id` can have value ('0') which is not present in `wp_rg_form.id` and `wp_fs_agents.id`. So it will only output values which are present. Question is, is it possible to output even those rows where mentioned values = 0, replacing `wp_fs_agents.name` and `wp_rg_form.title` in those row with "All";
I think, for replacing it would be something like

```
IF(`agent_id` = '0', 'All', `wp_fs_agents`.`name`) as `name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a left JOIN and COALESCE function:

```
SELECT
  `wp_fs_reports`.*,
  COALESCE(`wp_fs_agents`.`name`,'All'),
  `wp_rg_form`.`title`
FROM
  `wp_fs_reports`
  LEFT JOIN `wp_rg_form` ON (`wp_fs_reports`.`form_id` = `wp_rg_form`.`id`) 
  LEFT JOIN `wp_fs_agents` ON(`wp_fs_reports`.`agent_id` = `wp_fs_agents`.`id`)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can left join to the `wp_fs_agents` table, which will include `wp_fs_reports` rows that don't have an `agent_id` in `wp_fs_agents`:

```
select
  wp_fs_reports.*,
  IF(wp_fs_reports.agent_id = '0', 'All', wp_fs_agents.name) as name,
  wp_rg_form.title
from wp_fs_reports
INNER JOIN wp_rg_form ON wp_fs_reports.form_id = wp_rg_form.id
LEFT JOIN wp_fs_agents ON wp_fs_reports.agent_id = wp_fs_agents.id
```

If there are `agent_id` values other than zero that aren't represented in the `wp_fs_agents` table, they'll also be in the results so you'll need some other way to exclude them.

Comment: thanks, this works, except it should be a bit different. Instead of `wp_rg_form.title` it should be `IF(wp_fs_reports.form_id = '0', 'All', wp_rg_form.title) as title`. And instead of inner it should be left. Also, you forgot ( after ON.